# Rails 3 + Nginx + Passenger -- Routing index

Tags: nginx, ruby-on-rails, phusion-passenger

I have no index.html file in my public folder. My rails routes file routes this, and it works fine when I run 'rails server' on my machine.

I'm trying to deploy the app. I have passenger and nginx running
When I run rails server on my local machine, it works fine. But it's just trying to access static file when I try to access it on the production server.

Here's my nginx conf:

```
worker_processes  1;
#pid        logs/nginx.pid;
events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}
http {
    passenger_root /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-3.0.2;
    passenger_ruby /usr/bin/ruby;
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;
    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  mmjconsult.com;
        root /www/mmjs/public;
        access_log  logs/host.access.log;
        passenger_enabled on;
    }
}
```

Thank you for any help. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Have you found out what your problem was?

I actually run into the same problem, and of course it was all my fault: I'm using capistrano to deploy my app, and just forgot that it sits in the "current" directory.
So instead of

```
root /var/www/myapp/public;
```

the app was actually in

```
root /var/www/myapp/current/public;
```

Hope this helps.

Rgds,
Rollo